# Prevent Activity against opening without required data inside Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I don't really know if there is any solution for that problem (maybe I'm looking for something impossible or uncommon thing), and I didn't found anything by searching this site or Google. My problem is a little bit complex, so please read the whole story.

In 2 of my activities there are parts which are completely equal. There's one that does the registration, and one that does the user's data modification. I need the same kind of data fields for both (first name, last name, email, etc.), and I need to validate them by the same method - so they're identical.

However, there are some view elements which are *not* the same, and the registration is called far away from the data modification. I need both of them without being in the way of each other. So my best (but maybe not very best) idea is the following:

The same parts of the layout are always declared and `VISIBLE`. Everything else is `GONE` by default, and are declared only if it is needed (of course they become `VISIBLE`, too). To decide which part of the activity should be used, I want to send extra data with `Intent`, what clearly defines, what I need to show on the activity.

It's something like this:

```
String contentToShow = getIntent().getStringExtra("contentToShow");

if (contentToShow.equals("register")){
    //show everything needed to registration
} else if (contentToShow.equals("userModification")){
    //show everything needed to user's data modification
}
```

Without the above lines, the activity would be opened with parts missing. Right now I would always use them as it should be, but if later it could be opened somehow (maybe by someone else) "accidentally" with no data inside `Intent`, it wouldn't be good.

So here is my question: **Is there any solution or guideline to prevent the activity from being opened if there isn't any required data sent with `Intent`?**

Comment: It's very unlikely that someone will open your activity accidentally without passing the data. In applications, it's not like you can try different URLs in the browser to get access to some data of a website. Still, if you want this, check for the data in the intent in your `onCreate()` method and if it's missing, open some other activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be really necessary to check the data in Intent. However, if you are worried, one way to check it is by using this in `onCreate()`:

```
if(!getIntent().hasExtra("someparameter"))
    finish();//finish your activity if intent extra is missing.
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)